# How to make a cell in a DATAGRID link to another Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, window

I get data from an SQL database into my DATAGRID on my WPF application. I want to be able to click a cell that is named : 'Left to audit' and from there get redirected to anothter page with all the information on how many is left to audit.

How do i go about creating the click event to take me to another page?

P.S. I am a Novice.

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGnHA.png

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU0bA.png - Want to click in the cells on the last column.

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: @Sheridan Sorry for the late reply, I tried a click event and have also tried Monika's method, however I want it to link to another window called xamlAllocateAudit on the same application but I don't know how? Any help please?

Comment: In your question, please show how you have populated the data in your `DataGrid`.

Comment: Should the program open a new window every time a cell is clicked, or should it recycle the same window (update it's data) when a new cell is clicked?

Comment: @Nautious We are loading up xamlAllocateAudit every time a new cell is clicked under a certain column, but with different data for each cell. So we need to know which cell has been clicked, the data within it and then pass this to the new form.

Comment: OK.. I have something for you.. Check answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

Add an EventSetter on the CellStyle:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.MouseLeftButtonDown"
                     Handler="CellClicked" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

In Code Behind add Handler:

```
private void CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    String cellContent = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;

    xamlAllocateAudit window = new xamlAllocateAudit
    {
        DataContext = cellContent
    }
    window.Show();
}
```

Works on my end.. First click selects cell, second click fires handler, which opens the new window.

if you want the same window to be updated, then keep a reference of the window, if existing, update it's datacontext.

On the ohter side in the xamlAllocateAudit, create handler for the event "DataContextChanged":

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.xamlAllocateAudit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DetailsWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    DataContextChanged="Window_DataContextChanged">
<!-- Some graphics -->
</Window>
```

And in CodeBehind:

```
private void Window_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newDataContext = e.NewValue;
    //do stuff with DataContext
}
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for the reply again, however I tried what you posted and it keeps coming up with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", pointing to the passing of data part. Any further help you could give, or a few examples of how I could best pass the data without getting errors?

Comment: Ok. What type of column do you use, and how does the ItemsSource of the DataGrid look like?

Comment: Edited original post with new link, so you can see for yourself. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I'm able to reproduce the error. I'm guessing the property "ToBeAudited" is typeof string. What does the "Employee" class look like?

Comment: We don't have an Employee class, it is just a method that uses an SQLconnector to a database table in SQL.

Comment: And how do I retrieve the DataContext on the other form.

Comment: Edited to add row datacontext to window, and fire event when datacontext is added.
Alternatively create bindings in the xaml of xamlAllocateAudit.

Comment: Thanks the navigation worked! However, using newDataContext how can I get the value that I clicked, in the cell, in the Datagrid?

Comment: edit CellClicked callback to only pass the selected Cell Contents.

Comment: So changed rowData = Cell.Content; and on other form, tried to display the newDataContext in a message box and it came up with "System.Windows.Controls.Textblock" in the message box. Can you give me some guidance? Told you i'm a novice haha

Comment: Yes. The cell content is the text block. If you only want the number showed by the text block, then cast the "sender" to textblock, and get its content directly via it's "Text"  property.

Comment: By the way, it's okay to be a novice. We have all been there. ;-)

Comment: Tried what you said and can't seem to do it, could you give me an example in your reply please?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this work:

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Link}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>

private void DG_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

If the URI points a website it will be opened with the default web-browser, if it is a folder it will be opened in explorer, if it is a file it will be opened with the default application associated with it.

To use this for autogenerated columns your property needs to be of type Uri so a DataGridHyperlinkColumn is generated. You then can hook up the event by placing the style in the DataGrid.Resources:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to open up another window on the application, what code would I add for my situation? My window is called xamlAllocateAudits.xaml